# Can you set buy weapon keys in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

What I mean is, is there a way you can set hotkeys for certain weapons? For example, if I am on the terrorists team in competitive and I can afford an ak, can I set a hotkey so that lets say if I press "L" it buys me an ak.

Comment: You can bind macros to your keyboard or special buttons on your mouse

Comment: @ErtürkÖztürk No need for that, they can use the "buy" command. (Nice to see a fellow Turk here in Arqade btw.)

Comment: @ardaozkal I answered as a casual cs player and fulltime programmer (I was just passing here lol)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Run the command `bind "L" "buy ak47"`, replace L with the key, ak47 with the weapon's name.

Comment: If you are too lazy to write them by hand, I googled and found a nice website that generates the command for you: http://csgobuynds.com/buy-binds-generator.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a website like http://csgobuynds.com/buy-binds-generator.html#/skg to help you out here.

1. Select Your Key
2. Select What weapon you want (this site is good, as
   you can set one key for both Teams)
3. Select if you want pistols, gear, nades
4. Press Generate
5. Copy the line of text and paste it in
   your console.